# Preact with styled-components causes error in browser console

Tags: webpack, styled-components, preact

Simply importing styled-components leads to this error in the browser console:

```
styled-components.browser.esm.js?face:1670 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _react.createContext) is not a function
    at Object.eval (styled-components.browser.esm.js?face:1670)
    at eval (styled-components.browser.esm.js:2490)
    at Object../node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js (vendors~index.js:167)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:79)
    at eval (index.js?12d5:2)
    at Object../src/index.js (index.js:165)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:79)
    at checkDeferredModules (index.js:46)
    at index.js:152
    at index.js:155
```

I'm using webpack, preact, Babel.

Code to reproduce is literally just this, in a new, empty build:

src/index.js:

```js
import { h, Component, render } from "preact"
import styled from "styled-components"
```

package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Web app.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist/* && NODE_ENV=development webpack -d --config webpack.conf.js --env development"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "preact": "^8.4.2",
    "preact-compat": "^3.18.4",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.28.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

webpack.conf.js:

```js
const path = require("path")
const webpack = require("webpack")
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: "./src/index.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/i,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            'babel-preset-env',
            'babel-preset-react'
          ],
          plugins: [
            [ 'babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx', {
              pragma: 'h'
            }],
          ]
        }
      }
    }]
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: ("http://your-hostname.com/"),
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].js'
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all'
    },
    occurrenceOrder: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new htmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html'
})
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react': 'preact-compat',
      'react-dom': 'preact-compat'
    }
  }
}
```

Build using `npm run build` works fine, but visiting the resulting page in the browser produces the above error.

Any pointers would be very gratefully received.

Edit:

According to [this issue logged against Preact-CLI](https://github.com/developit/preact-cli/issues/672), preact does not have react's `contextApi` so I should downgrade `styled-components` to v3 instead of v4. Downgrading does indeed seem to resolve the issue.

Confusingly though, Jason Miller, author of preact, says [in a tweet](https://twitter.com/_developit/status/843536715587502080?lang=en) that "preact supports context just fine". I'm probably misunderstanding this.

Comment: That tweet was from 2017, React's new context api's only been out since March 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here https://github.com/developit/preact-cli/issues/672#issuecomment-440985092 and my edit above.

Downgrading `styled-components` from v4 to v3 "fixes" the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I work on preact.

You're seeing this error because the `createContext`-API is not supported in Preact 8.x. It will be part of our next major release which is right around the corner. We're currently in beta status and are hoping to move forward to a release candidate soon.

If you absolutely need `styled-components` to work with Preact 8.x, then your only option is to downgrade to `styled-components` V3 like @ukosteopath suggested.

Comment: For anyone who finds this, Preact's next major release, Preact X, is almost stable! https://github.com/preactjs/preact/releases